# SQUID Ubuntu - Can you connect to a Squid proxy from another network

Tags: server, proxy, squid

I've been playing with Squid in Ubuntu to set up a proxy server I can use when I'm out of the country.

I was able to set it up so that any device in the proxy's network can connect through it, but realised that it might be limited to just that.

So, Is it possible to connect to the squid proxy from another network? If so, what should I do/change?

Any suggestion/advice is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: how does this relate to ubuntu?

Comment: Sure. You can do this. Open an external port and setup some user/password.